# Error call to SSPI with my WebService in C#

Tags: c#, ssl

I am developing a WebService in C # however I am facing an error.
This is the error :

```
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The message or signature supplied for verification has been altered
```

So I sometimes get this error when I open my MySQL connection in my WebService.
I had this error by launching my webService twice at the same time then I tried again and no more errors.

My web service is on a Windows server 2012 R2 and i'm using .NET Framework 4.7.2 (It is called by the website php).

I did quite a bit of internet research and came across this in C# :

**ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;**

But it doesn't work, Do you have any idea so that I do not face this problem again ?

There is my MySQL open connection method :

```
    public MySqlConnection OpenConnectionDB(string clientId)
    {
        listVerifs = new List<string>();
        int iConn = 0;
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection sqlCo = new MySqlConnection("server=MyServer;database=" + this.db + ";username=MyUID;password=MyPwd;AllowLoadLocalInfile=true");

            if (sqlCo.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                sqlCo.Open();
            }

            listVerifs.Add("CO SQL");

            dataSourceDBF = @"//ntserver/Winbooks_Data/winbooks/data/" + clientId + "/";
            dbfCo = new AdsConnection(@"data Source=//ntserver/Winbooks_Data/winbooks/data/" + clientId + "/" + clientId + ".add;User ID=mYUID;Password=;ServerType=local;ReadOnly=true;pooling=true;TrimTrailingSpaces=true;TableType=CDX;LockMode=COMPATIBLE");

            if (dbfCo.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                dbfCo.Open();
            }

            listVerifs.Add("CO DBF");
            Console.WriteLine("Databases connections open succesfull");
            return sqlCo;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            dbfCo = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Error connection " + e.Message);
            test = e.Message;
            log.AddLog("Erreur Fonction OpenConnectionDB : " + e.ToString(), 3, "WebServiceMySQL");
            return null;
        }
```

Thank's in advance !

Comment: Can you post an example of how you connect to your MySQL database?

Comment: @CameronTinker Yes i edited my post ! ;)

Comment: Are you using a corporate network to test this? Are you able to test with another internet connection (your home connection, or mobile phone access point?) (that would be to rule out https certificate interception / replacement by the corporate network)